# ASP.NET Page.User.Identity.Name is blank on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

When I run my intranet app on our server the Page.User.Identity.Name is blank. In IIS 7.5 if I disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication then it prompts me for userid/pw when I access the site. When I enter my info into Chrome it works great. When I try from IE 8 (which everyone at this company uses :( ) it doesn't work at all. It just keeps prompting me.

How can I remove this prompt? Since people are logged into Windows into our network I wouldn't think it would be prompting me. Also, any idea why Chrome seems to handle this but IE 8 doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

resolved by adding the above code?

Comment: This gives the same result.